# rerun scripts after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a content into a div with this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


    $(".produkty").click(function(){
        var post_id = $(this).attr("href");    
        $("#single_product_box").load(post_id + " #main" );
        return false;
     });
});
```

The other scripts I use are here:

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>


   $(function() {
       $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
         btnNext: ".next-any",
         btnPrev: ".prev-any"
       });
   });
   $(function() {
       $(".anyClass-2").jCarouselLite({
         btnNext: ".next-any2",
         btnPrev: ".prev-any2"

       });
   });
```

Everything is fine, but after first load it stopped working. I've tried to use something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '$post_id',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (data) {
        $('#single_product_box').html("Loading...");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data!='error'){
            $('#single_product_box').html(data);
        }else{
            $('#single_product_box').html("<span style='color:red;'>Error!</span>");
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        $('#single_product_box').html("<span class='error'>Error!</span>");
    }
});
```

but I cannot make it work again, I even tried to put the scripts into loaded content, but it disappears as well. I just had no more ideas.

Comment: Are you replacing produckty in ajax response . and what exactly stops working .the click or caraousal .

Comment: No I dont replace 'produkty' at least I think so , The carousal stopped working. Hm heres the website so maybe it will be easier to understand. There are 2 boxes, in the middle 1 with 9 thumbanails and one with description , there is a carousel in the right box on the bottom .

Comment: Looks like jQuery is being loaded twice. That's why your carousel stops working (the plugins which registered themselves are no longer registered...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to have the same result as `.load`, but with AJAX. First, your url should be your variable, not a string with a PHP variable. Then on complete, you need to find the target :

```
$.ajax({
    url: post_id, //Your URL should be your variable
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (data) {
        $('#single_product_box').html("Loading...");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data!='error'){
            //Have to target you element.
            $('#single_product_box').html($(data).find('#main')); //Here i'm not sure if you should add .html();
        }else{
            $('#single_product_box').html("<span style='color:red;'>Error!</span>");
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        $('#single_product_box').html("<span class='error'>Error!</span>");
    }
});
```

Now that you have the content, you have the same problem about the carrousel. Just retrigger the carousel!

To do that, you'll have to change the `dataType` to `text`, because your page is reloading jQuery. When you reload it, it remove the prototype method `jCarouselLite` and can't access it.

After appending the HTML, you can use the same line of code you are using on the DOM ready!

## Here the final code

```
$.ajax({
    url: post_id, //Your URL should be your variable
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'text', //Passing text here will prevent the script from runnig. Script were overriding jCarousel and couldnt active it again
    beforeSend: function (data) {
        $('#single_product_box').html("Loading...");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data!='error'){
            //Have to target you element.
            var html = $(data).find('#main');
            $('#single_product_box').html(html);
            
            //Retrigger the carousel!
            $(".anyClass-2").jCarouselLite({
                btnNext: ".next-any2",
                btnPrev: ".prev-any2"
                
            });
        }else{
            $('#single_product_box').html("<span style='color:red;'>Error!</span>");
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        $('#single_product_box').html("<span class='error'>Error!</span>");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks ;) however, can I make a loop with that or something like that ?

Comment: @MateuszWinnicki Can you tell me more about that loop? it is never a good idea to put any XHR request in a loop. What do you wanna do?

Comment: Hm.. I got there categories which i'd like to load by ajax as well, however after each ajax function, jquery removes itself. I'll edit my post with new part of code ;)

Comment: @MateuszWinnicki You shouldn't edit the answer to add your code ;) Can i know what is `.page-numbers`?

Comment: ops, sorry acutally here `.page-numbers` is just another link. when you go for example to the first `li` of the headphones category, there you go >>> for next page. So after I go to nextpage the script removes again , so I tried to add this again after succes, it worked but only for the first time going to the next page, When I wanted to go back It didnt load the data, but redirect. Hm, I dont know if its clear enough ;) Trying hard to explain it well ;)

Comment: Hm, the easiest way at least I think so, is to make a function which reruns all jquery scripts after each ajax use. however i dont know how to make it works ;)

Comment: At that point, i think event delegation is your solution. You'll pardon my laziness but I don't feel like explaining that concept since there is already a lot of information about on SO. **Anyway**, try a code like this : http://pastebin.com/zAygnY9J

Comment: Of course, since both request are the same, you could make a function : http://pastebin.com/xb5w4ETN;

Comment: oh awesome ;) man so now I need to add the same function for loading products ? Cuz now after I go to nextpage of category, the script with product being loaded removes as well ;( so it redirects ...

Comment: @MateuszWinnicki turn you function into a delegation aswell : `$('#categories_box').on('click', ".produkty", function(){you current code})`

Comment: oh man love you ;) and if I rerun the carousel in this delegation it will be working all the time ? ;)

Comment: Oh so i didnt pass the value for the function earlier ;) Nice, you know what actually this carousel doesnt work , but i guess its becouse of libreary of jcarousel not being loaded as well.

Comment: @MateuszWinnicki that's wierd... sometime it work, sometime it don't. I can't put my finger on why... Sorry

Comment: You know what, let try something sketchy. On DOM ready, try to assign the carousel to an other prototype : `$.fn.myCarousel = $.fn. jCarouselLite` then, everytime you call carousel, use `myCarousel` : `$(".anyClass-2").myCarousel({
                btnNext: ".next-any2",
                btnPrev: ".prev-any2"

            });`

Comment: I got Undefine Error with this, on line with calling `.myCarousel` - so it's like no library to me.

Comment: @MateuszWinnicki Well, my last guess is that jQuery is still being load even with the `dataType` set. Try being in a no conflict universe. `$j = jQuery.noConflict()` at the start and then replace all `$` to `$j`. If that doesn't work, i'll be helpless...

Comment: Hey man ;) thank you so much I did make it works ;) If there is anything I can help you with as well please let me know ;) I'll try to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, it looks like jQuery is being loaded multiple times (which is another issue - you need to look into cleaning up your mark up). All of the plugins that register prior are lost (because they use the loaded `$.fn`, which is overwritten when a later jQuery is loaded...)

I see the following your HTML

```
Line 32
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://usb-solutions.pl/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>    

Line 40
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Line 323
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $.getScript("http://usb-solutions.pl/wp-content/themes/usb-solutions/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js");
    $.getScript("//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js");
</script>
```

Comment: Hm The line 323 i added as an experiment, it didtn work without that line, and it doesnt with it ;) So what is the solution ? Jquery noConflict, maybe  ? Also that line 323 disappears after content is being loaded ;)